# OrientDB - reached maximum pool size for given partition (with JDBC)

Tags: java, jdbc, orientdb

Good evening,

I have a server which queries an OrientDB database using the JDBC connector:

```
        Connection _connection = (OrientJdbcConnection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:orient:remote:" + host + "/" + dbName, user, password);
```

I've set script.pool.maxSize = 50. Whenever I do a query, e.g:

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery("select getRouteWithAttributes('" + sessionID + "') as route");
stmt.close();
```

I can see it by consulting LIST CONNECTIONS, like in the figure below(7 queries where made just before the snapshot):

[image: LIST CONNECTIONS]

But if I keep on querying the system, the active connections list will increase and each query will remain in the list for approximately a minute. So when more than 50 queries are done, I get "java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have reached maximum pool size for given partition".

What is the best approach to take here? Increasing the db.pool.size parameter to huge values does not seem very correct...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you close the connection?

Comment: Shouldn't I keep the connection open until the server is turned off? Only the server(jersey) queries the database as the clients send requests to the server. The client app doesnt query the db directly.

Comment: Please call connection.close() to release it.

Comment: Should I open and close connection each time the server queries the orientDB?

Comment: What about the connection pool? Should I set the "script.pool.maxSize" paramater to an high value (such as the max number of queries I'm expecting orient to receive simultaneously, e.g 500) and a smaller value for "db.pool.max" parameter (e.g 10)? The connection pool will take care of it?